# Pass id or entire object between activites?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity containing a ListFragment. It's populated from a restful webservice. When I click on an item in the list I send back the id of that item to my activity. And using an intent pass that on to a second detail activity and request the object by id from the webservice again.

I'm considering if I should send the object, instead of just it's id, to the detail activity? That would save me a http request and make things a little less complicated.

However that would also mean that I'm required to have the entire object and in the futura that might be not be the case... what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only pass ids, and heres why:

- Passing Objects is slow or complicated when using Parcable
- When passing objects directly you have highly coupled services (activities), which is bad practice, handle activities as if they are in their own process (which actually happens in certain situations, e.g. calling activity from anohter app)
- Your object could be already out of date (e.g. user browses the list for couple of minutes and then opens an item)

The problem that you have an additional http request SHOULD be mitigated by good design of your backend, meaning you should have http cache features implemented (e.g. [etags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), [last-modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) cache-control headers,etc). This will give you the advantage that you always have the latest data from your server but only if needed. This should happen transparently so not to complicate your logic (check out Volley e.g.), also if you cannot use the http cache header and behavoiur have a local cache work in front of your http client.

Answer (score 1):

When designing web services to be consumed by Android device I always try to follow the approach of list items returning just the item id and then providing separate call to get the details. This allows you to lazily load only the data the user showed interest in (if he is interested in just one out of 50 items, why would you fetch all of them at the same go?)

Also, keep in mind, that there is limitation on the data size of a `Bundle`, this meaning that the data transfer using intents should be limited. The cool thing is that if you go off the size, the bundle is just omitted all together and no meaningful error is shown.